# Eigenvalues of adjacent matrix

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a regular graph and suppose, the eigenvalues of its adjacent matrix are $-2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1,$ and $4$.

How would you

1. find the number of vertices, edges and degrees of the graph $G$.
2. the minimum spanning tree of the graph $G$?

Comment: Here's a hint to get you started: What's the product of the adjacency matrix and the "all-$1$s" vector?