# Eigenvalues of Adjacency Matrix are Integer?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

There are some related discussions here:
[Computation of Eigenvalues of Adjacency Matrix of Cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554959/computation-of-eigenvalues-of-adjacency-matrix-of-cycle)
[Eigenvalues of adjacent matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580045/eigenvalues-of-adjacent-matrix)
[eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of bipartite graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520589/eigenvalue-of-adjacency-matrix-of-bipartite-graph)

However, is there a way to prove that eigenvalues of adjacency matrix of any graph are integer?

The graph should obey

1. connected
2. undirected
3. edges weight are $1$

I know the trace of adjacency matrix is $0$. However, is there intuitive way or formal proof to say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample for your conjecture. Let $p, q$ be distinct primes, and consider the graph $K_{p,q}$. We note that the eigenvalues of $K_{p, q}$ are $\pm \sqrt{pq}$ and $0^{pq-2}$. Now $\sqrt{pq}$ is certainly not an integer.

Comment: What is the graph for $K_{p,q}$? regular graph or?

Comment: The complete bipartite graph, with part sizes $p$ and $q$.

Comment: But is it connected?  It looks like it is not connected..   (the first picture)   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBipartiteGraph.html

Comment: Yes. WolframAlpha is showing multiple examples next to each other. For the graph $K_{m, n}$, draw $m$ vertices in one part and $n$ vertices in the other. Then add all possible edges between the two parts.